# C++ typedef for templated class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

What's the best way to create an alias for a templated class in C++?

```
template<typename T>
class Dummy1
{
public:
    Dummy1(T var) : myVar1(var) {
    }
    ~Dummy1() {
    }
private:
    T myVar1;
};
```

C style would be:

```
typedef Dummy1<int> DummyInt;
```

In C++, as far as I know, I would write:

```
class DummyInt : public Dummy1<int> 
{
    DummyInt(int a) : Dummy1<int>(a) { }
    ~DummyInt() { }
}
```

Is there a better/shorter way? Cause this way when I inherit from the base, I have to declare the constructors every time.

I need an alias for `Dummy1<int>` otherwise I need to use the template option through the entire code (like pointers and references). But I would like to *not* do this.

Answer (score 8):

If you just *must* use inheritance then you can avoid repeating the constructors in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and onward by just inheriting them:

```
struct DummyInt : Dummy1<int> {
  using Dummy1::Dummy1;
};
```

Otherwise, just use an alias like you do. If you want it to not be the "C way" you can employ the modern C++ style:

```
using DummyInt = Dummy1<int>;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just as well use a typedef or a using in C++

```
typedef Dummy1<int> DummyInt;
using DummyInt = Dummy1<int>;
```

You dont see typedef anymore in modern C++ code IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer (C++11 and after):

```
using DummyInt = Dummy1<int>;
```

No reason not to use an alias here, in my opinion.